# Special characters (subscripts) not shown proprely

Tags: sql-server, subscript

I want to put some chemical data into columns in the table. But in existing table subscripts are shown as normal characters. Some of them are shown as a question marks. What Am I supposed to do to fix it?

When I type this code

```
 SELECT N'H' + NCHAR(0x2082) + N'O'
```

It shows "H<sub>2</sub>O" properly

When I put it into existing table

```
 INSERT INTO tab (id, label)
 VALUES('100', N'H' + NCHAR(0x2082) + N'O')
```

It shows "H2O" not correctly

Comment: What **datatype** is your `label` column??

Comment: your problem is to store and display unicode characters correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` column in your table instead of `VARCHAR` / `CHAR` to store unicode characters.

In the example below, `@table1`, stores the formula correctly using `NVARCHAR` datatype whereas `@table2` stores the same value in a `VARCHAR` column

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    ID int,
    formula NVARCHAR(5)
)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
    ID int,
    formula VARCHAR(5)
)

insert into @table1
SELECT '100', N'H' + NCHAR(0x2082) + N'O'

insert into @table2
SELECT '100', N'H' + NCHAR(0x2082) + N'O'

SELECT * FROM @table1;
SELECT * FROM @table2;
```